# Is there a way to run an application in the background without it ever being closed

Tags: background-process

I have a moto g4 play and theres a feature that makes the ringtones/notifications ascend, which sometimes makes it so I can't even tell the sounds are going off. There's a weird workaround that if I use this application that I downloaded from the play store, it blocks the ascending sound. the thing is, the app keeps closing every so often. Is there a way to permanently keep it going in the background without it ever closing?

Comment: "I use this application that I downloaded from the play store" -> what app? You didn't include a link.

Comment: Also, instead of dealing with this secondary problem, I think it's best you dig into settings and turn off "**increasing ring volume**" or a similar option to tackle the primary one.